# How to link two stylesheets to a component in Stenciljs?

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I want to link two sass stylesheets (scss) to a single component.
This is what I want: `styleUrls: ['./my-component.scss', '../../index.scss']`

I have an `index.scss` in the root of the project, which imports another stylesheet together with the stylesheets of every component. Up until now, the way it worked was that, every component was linked to the `index.scss`, but the issue with that is that that meant that all the styles are applied to all the components, and I don't want that. I want to apply only the stylesheet of the component to the component itself PLUS another stylesheet that is common for all components.

I was thinking maybe there is some other way to structure my project in a way that the common stylesheet is imported inside the `index.scss`, but then I don't know how do I link each component to their own stylesheet only.

I tried this: `styleUrls: ['./my-component.scss', '../../index.scss']`
but it does not work. Only the first stylesheet is being applied, while the second ignored.